# rake assets:precompile doesn't do anything :( Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sprockets

I replaced my OS on my PC with a new one. Previously `assets:precompile` is working but now it doesn't do anything at all :( no logs, error message or whatsoever. this is the command I tried.

> RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails assets:precompile

I believe my sprockets has been updated to beta13 and I'm using V8 engine in therubyracer

Could you help me find what's wrong with my system?

Thanks :)

Comment: @died I did not upgrade my OS. Previously, I have Ubuntu 11.04, the full one, then I reinstalled the same OS, but this time, just the CLI (minimal) and then installed Gnome 3.

Comment: I don’t know if this is normal or not, but I would like to suggest this question be deleted. It’s been viewed 1.4k times, and surely most of those people don’t really find what they want here since this was a transient problem affecting Rails for a very brief period of time (what, a couple days?). Removing the question would likely reduce the time it takes people to find their actual solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well as suggested, I have to give at least an answer to my question.

Apparently, the latest update of rails 3.1 gems dependency, sprockets was updated to beta13, and with that, rake assets:precompile does not work anymore.

I don't know, and I'm still looking what went wrong, or did I missed configuring anything. Will look more into that.

EDIT:

Sprockets released 2.0 beta 13 to be compatible with Rails 3.1 RC5. I had to upgrade to RC5 for this to work.

Comment: Delete public/assets and then run $ rake assets:precompile. In your case, the 'assets' folder and its contents won't be re-created, right? What is the output of running $ rake assets:precompile --trace?

Comment: Previously, no output at all. But I got all working now, will edit the answer for further details.